# How to calculate duration between two times in Google scripts for spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I would like to create a custom function that calculates the duration between two or more hours. The result can be positive or negative.

Other people can benefit using the function in any given coordinates not limiting to a specific range.

Example input:

```
 Inputs:                 Output:
 A      B       C        D

-26:55  06:38   22:39   -04:16
 02:19  00:00   04:33    02:19
```

I've tried without success many alternatives:

```js
function saldo(A,B,C) { // best desired...

if(A == 0) {
    return (-B)+C ;
}
else if (A<0 && (-A)<C && (-A)-C<B){
    return (A)+C-B;
}
else if (A<0 && (-A)>C){
    return (-B);
}


function xis(A,B) {

// var addedDate = sheet.getRange(1,1).getValue();
//  var a1 = Utilities.formatDate(A, SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "HH:mm");  
//  var b1 = Utilities.formatDate(B, SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "HH:mm");   


var a1 =  new Date.getHours(A) + date.getMinutes(A);
var b1 =  new Date.getHours(B) + date.getMinutes(B);

  if (a1 > b1){

    return B;
  }

  else {
    return A;
  }

}



function tentativa(a,b){
  var t1 = a.getTime();
  var t2 = b.getTime();

var outnumber =  t1 - t2;

  return Utilities.formatDate(new Date(outnumber), "GMT-3", "hh:mm");  
}

function worked(time1,time2)      
{                                 
//var time1;
//var time2;
var outnumber = time1 - time2;  
 // return msToTime(outnumber) 
  return msToTime(outnumber);
 //  return Utilities.formatDate(new Date(outnumber), "GMT", "HH:mm");  
}

function msToTime(duration) {
    var milliseconds = parseInt((duration%1000)/100)
       , seconds = parseInt((duration/1000)%60)
       , minutes = parseInt((duration/(1000*60))%60)
        , hours = parseInt((duration/(1000*60*60))%24);

  //  hours = hours : hours;
  //  minutes =  minutes : minutes;
  //   seconds = (seconds < 10) ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
}
```

Comment: Are you just re-asking [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29987856/google-scripts-subtracting-times) you asked yesterday?

Comment: I'm not re-asking this question, I've tried to post the previous question but failed and I did one more try.

Answer (score 1):

**You should only need 2 inputs to find the difference between two hour variables.**

I have a small javascript [code snippet](https://github.com/hn81/js_/blob/master/hourDiff.js) which takes 2 inputs in `hh:mm` format and outputs the difference. You could extrapolate this logic for `hh:mm:ss` formats. You can call the function repeatedly to solve for 3 or more inputs.

```
// Code snippet to calculate the difference between 2 inputs of time in hh:mm 24hrs format
// Author: Harish Narayanan
// Date: 04-May-2015

function getHourDiff(a, b) {
    if (!isValidHour(a) || !isValidHour(b)) {
        return "Invalid input(s)";
    }

    var h1 = a.split(":"), h2 = b.split(":");
    var h = 0, m = 0;
    h = h1[0] - h2[0];
    m = h1[1] - h2[1];

    if (h < 0) {
        h = -h; 
        m = -m;
    }
    if (h == 0) {
        m = Math.abs(m);
    }
    if (m < 0) {
        m = m + 60;
        h = h - 1;
    }

    return h+":"+m;
}

function isValidHour(hour) {
    hourPattern = "^([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$";
    if (hour.match(hourPattern)) {return true;}
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @EricLeschinski I understand your point. I also offered an answer that the original poster could use to extrapolate. So I want to see if this helped the  the OP before removing the answer.

Comment: It's a good answer, every stackoverflow answer should be reserved for specific and definitive answer to a specific question.  In this case the OP didn't ask a specific question, so I edited the original question to make specific and explicit what he wants, then changed your answer to answer that.  Also it's good to always paste in the code from the external site into the answer if it fits in neatly.  (Always expect external links to go down). Playing 20 questions with a person who who is looking for guidance is generally a recipe for down votes since stackoverflow is not a forum.

Comment: @EricLeschinski: It's a valid point that links might go down.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't try yet, this week I will study your answer attentively. I thank you very much for your time to answer this difficult question.

Comment: Message error: TypeError: Não é possível chamar o método "match" de undefined.Dispensar

Comment: @VagnerGuilhermedaSilva : can you tell in which code you are facing this error and translate the error message to English? at which line do you see this error?

Comment: I`m very sorry... TypeError: Cannot call method "match" of undefined. (line refers to if(hour.match)

Comment: The reason why I want to know the solution is to help work with hours and using advanced calculations and in any coordinates. In this case, I have a big data of hours from a company where I want to find out how to better manage this data intelligently. "A" refers to leftover of the previous month , " B " refers to the extra time in the month, " C " refers to the compensation time and "D " refers to the calculation result . Only " B" and " C can be extracted from the system. " A " and" D " should be the result achieved.

Comment: It seems the argument passed to isValid() method is undefined. How are you invoking the function getHourDiff()? Remember it needs 2 inputs in this format: "hh:mm" Ex: 23:40.

Comment: I'm getting the error message: TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined